# Pass additional N textures to a custom shader in cocos2d

Tags: c++11, opengl, glsl, cocos2d-x, fragment-shader

I want to pass N number of texture to a custom shader. As I surfed thru net, the best option I've got is to override the Sprite::draw() function and add a CustomCommand object to the draw pool.

CPP file:

```
void SpriteSub::draw(Renderer *renderer, const Mat4 &transform, uint32_t flags) {

    m_cmdCustom.init(_globalZOrder, transform, flags);
    m_cmdCustom.func = CC_CALLBACK_0(SpriteSub::onDraw, this, transform, flags);
    renderer->addCommand(&m_cmdCustom);

    Sprite::draw(renderer, transform, flags);

}

void SpriteSub::onDraw(const Mat4 &transform, uint32_t /*flags*/) {

    this->getGLProgram()->use();

    auto wwProgram = m_shader->getProgram();

    auto texBall0 = Director::getInstance()->getTextureCache()->addImage("ball.png")->getName();
    GLuint locTexIcon0 = glGetUniformLocation(wwProgram, "texBall0");
    glUniform1i(locTexIcon0, 0);
    //glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + 0); glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texBall0);
    //glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + 0);
    GL::bindTexture2D(texBall0);

}
```

frament shader:

```
    #ifdef GL_ES
    precision lowp float;
    #endif

    varying vec4 v_fragmentColor;
    varying vec2 v_texCoord;

    uniform sampler2D texBall0;
    uniform sampler2D texBall1;
    //uniform sampler2D texBall2;
    //uniform sampler2D texBall3;
    //uniform sampler2D texBall4;
    //uniform sampler2D texBall5;

    void main()
    {

        float t = 0.7f;

        //gl_FragColor = texture2D(CC_Texture0, v_texCoord);

        //this is just a sample code
        gl_FragColor = texture2D(texBall0, v_texCoord) * t;
        gl_FragColor += texture2D(texBall1, v_texCoord) * (t-1);

        //some code that uses the other textures...

    }
```

The shader above is just a sample and not the actual code I'm using. For now, I just need to successfully pass multiple textures in a single shader to process their pixels.

Currently, I can't display the passed texture. What should be done to achieve this? Does Sprite::draw() in SpriteSub::draw() cancel-out the gl commands from onDraw()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Solved it!

You don't even need to override the draw or add a `CustomCommand` to render queue.

**Steps:**

1.) Create a `GLProgramState` with the `GLProgram` object you created with your custom shaders.

2.) Use `GLProgramState::setUniformTexture("uniformVarName", tex2D)` to locate uniform variable and pass texture name.

3.) Call `sprite->setGLProgramState(programState)` instead of `sprite->setGLProgram(program)`;

CCP File:

```
m_shader = GLProgram::createWithByteArrays(ccPositionTextureColor_noMVP_vert, shader_frag);
m_shader->retain();

auto shaderState = GLProgramState::getOrCreateWithGLProgram(m_shader);

auto textureCache = Director::getInstance()->getTextureCache();
auto img0 = textureCache->addImage("icon_tex0.png")->getName();
auto img1 = textureCache->addImage("icon_tex1.png")->getName();
auto img2 = textureCache->addImage("icon_tex2.png")->getName();
auto img3 = textureCache->addImage("icon_tex3.png")->getName();
auto img4 = textureCache->addImage("icon_tex4.png")->getName();
auto img5 = textureCache->addImage("icon_tex5.png")->getName();

shaderState->setUniformTexture("texIcon0", img0);
shaderState->setUniformTexture("texIcon1", img1);
shaderState->setUniformTexture("texIcon2", img2);
shaderState->setUniformTexture("texIcon3", img3);
shaderState->setUniformTexture("texIcon4", img4);
shaderState->setUniformTexture("texIcon5", img5);

//this->setGLProgram(m_shader);
this->setGLProgramState(shaderState);
```

fragment shader:

```
    #ifdef GL_ES
    precision lowp float;
    #endif

    varying vec4 v_fragmentColor;
    varying vec2 v_texCoord;

    uniform sampler2D texIcon0;
    uniform sampler2D texIcon1;
    uniform sampler2D texIcon2;
    uniform sampler2D texIcon3;
    uniform sampler2D texIcon4;
    uniform sampler2D texIcon5;

    void main()
    {

        int numTex = 6;
        float fWeight = 1.0f/float(length);

        //gl_FragColor = texture2D(CC_Texture0, v_texCoord);
        gl_FragColor += texture2D(texIcon0, v_texCoord) * fWeight;
        gl_FragColor += texture2D(texIcon1, v_texCoord) * fWeight;
        gl_FragColor += texture2D(texIcon2, v_texCoord) * fWeight;
        gl_FragColor += texture2D(texIcon3, v_texCoord) * fWeight;
        gl_FragColor += texture2D(texIcon4, v_texCoord) * fWeight;
        gl_FragColor += texture2D(texIcon5, v_texCoord) * fWeight;


    }
```

sources:

- http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/solved-passing-a-variable-to-a-shader/27141/3
- http://cocos2d-x.org/docs/programmers-guide/advanced_topics/index.html#customizing-shaders